# OpenCV does not detect object if size of object is different from the target image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am developing my computer vision skills So I made a script to detect things inside the screen

We have this script I've put the disclosure image
The problem is that when you zoom in and out, it is not detected

[image: Detection succeeded with zoom 273%]

[image: Detection fails with zoom 205%]

```
import keyboard
import mss
import cv2
import numpy
from time import time, sleep
import pyautogui

pyautogui.PAUSE = 0

sct = mss.mss()
dimensions_left = {'left': 0,'top': 0,'width': 2560,'height': 1440}

print("Press 's' to start playing.")
print("Once started press 'p' to quit.")
keyboard.wait('s')

detect = cv2.imread('scend.png', cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
w = detect.shape[1]
h = detect.shape[0]
ww , hh = int(w/2),int(h/2)

fps_time = time()

while True:
    im = numpy.array(sct.grab(dimensions_left))
    im = numpy.flip(im[9:, 9:, :1], 2)  # 1
    im = cv2.resize(im, (1000, 500))
    im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(im, detect, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

    threshold = .4
    yloc, xloc = numpy.where(result >= threshold)

    rectangles = []
    for (x, y) in zip(xloc, yloc):
        rectangles.append([int(x), int(y), int(w), int(h)])
        rectangles.append([int(x), int(y), int(w), int(h)])

    rectangles, weights = cv2.groupRectangles(rectangles, 1, 0.2)

    for (x, y, w, h) in rectangles:
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x + ww, y + hh), (x + w - ww, y + h - hh), (0, 0, 255), 5)

        # pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, 0)

    cv2.imshow('Screen Shot', im)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
        break

    print('FPS: {}'.format(1 / (time() - fps_time)))
    fps_time = time()
```

Comment: matchTemplate is not scale-invariant. You could use a scale space pyramid and try to detect in each scale

Comment: @Micka Thank you very much, I solved the problem thanks to you, but I searched a lot and tried a lot and improved my experience thanks to what you said